# Status 403: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission

Tags: azure-authentication, azure-storage-account

To list containers in my storage account, I used Postman Rest API by generating tokens using this endpoint:

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/token
 &client_id = redacted
 &grant_type = client_credentials
 &resource = https://storage.azure.com
 &client_secret = redacted
```

With this token I queried the list of containers like this:

GET https://storageaccname.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list

Authorization : Bearer redacted

x-ms-version : 2017-11-09

But I got stuck at this error, I tried many ways to get rid of it no use :(

```
<?xml  version="1.0"  encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code>
<Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:
Time:2022-08-15T08:12:24.9827677Z</Message>
</Error>
```

I tried assigning API permissions to Azure storage and did the same process but still same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I generated access token with same token endpoint (v1.0) and got the same error while running the query like below:

```json
GET https://storageaccname.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, assign **`Storage Blob Data Contributor Role`** to your Service Principal like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Storage Accounts -> Your Storage Account -> Access Control (IAM) -> Add role assignment***

[image]

***If the error still persists, make use of v2.0 token endpoint to generate access token:***

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/Tenant_ID/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

**Response:**

[image]

Using above generated token, **I got the list of containers in my storage account successfully** like below:

[image]

Comment: Still got the error even after assigning that role like you said, using v2.0 in token endpoint did the trick. Thanks a lot!!