# Azure Rest API using Postman

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, postman, azure-storage, azure-rbac

I'm trying to use postman to get the blobs from a container, I'm trying to do this from a collection. Link below:
[https://www.postman.com/speeding-astronaut-338068/workspace/azure-rest-api/request/13081473-85754311-416e-459a-a38d-fd37e4933bc4](https://collection%20api%20rest%20azure)

First I go to a route named:

```
Get Storage Bearer Token
```

Where can I get my access_token by making this request:
[image]

above, I get my access_token successfully.
Then I go to the `List Blobs` route, and fill in the url with the appropriate storage account names and container name

[image]

but I get this error:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code>
    <Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:606c7212-201e-0005-3583-f1ab58000000
Time:2023-09-27T20:46:55.2555893Z</Message>
</Error>
```

Why even providing all the correct variables do I receive this error? I read some articles like:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/779065/error-this-request-is-not-authorized-to-perform-th

but I couldn't solve it because the error persists

to receive my client_id, client_secret I followed this tutorial:

https://docs.lacework.net/onboarding/gather-the-required-azure-client-id-tenant-id-and-client-secret
I have also given read permission to the service in my container and storage account

Comment: We can’t help unless you provide more information. Please edit your question to improve it. For a start, we need to know the details of your “list blobs” request, including the URL, the parameters and the headers.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the RBAC roles assigned to the user/service principal for which the token is acquired. More than likely, the error is coming because the user/service principal does not have proper RBAC roles.

Comment: I love how you've posted your access_token for all the world to see...

Comment: try using it there and tell me the result @Dai

Comment: I edited the question gentlemen @BrettDonald

Comment: "I have also given read permission to the service in my container and storage account" - Did you assign Reader role or Storage Blob Data Reader role?

Comment: reader function only
I wanted to give maximum permission to this service, create, read, delete and update @GauravMantri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error usually occurs if the service principal does not have required **RBAC roles** or **permissions** to perform the operation.

I registered one Azure AD application and added **API permission** like this:

[image]

Now, I added **Reader** role to above service principal under storage account:

[image]

I generated access token using **client credentials** flow via Postman with same parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:appId
client_secret:secret
resource: https://storage.azure.com
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to list blobs by running below REST API call, I got **same error** like this:

```http
GET https://sristorage28.blob.core.windows.net/sri?restype=container&comp=list
Authorization: Bearer <token>
x-ms-date: 2020-10-02
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, you **cannot** perform data operations like create, read, delete and update on storage account containers with **`Reader`** role.
>
> To **resolve** the error, you need to assign Storage related RBAC roles like ***Storage Blob Data Contributor*** or ***Storage Blob Data Owner***.

In my case, I assigned **Storage Blob Data Contributor** to the service principal under storage account like this:

[image]

When I call the REST API after assigning above role by generating **new bearer** token, I got **response** with list of blobs successfully:

```http
GET https://sristorage28.blob.core.windows.net/sri?restype=container&comp=list
Authorization: Bearer <token>
x-ms-date: 2020-10-02
```

**Response:**

[image]

If the error still persists, try generating access token using **v2.0 token** endpoint as I mentioned in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73388655/status-403-this-request-is-not-authorized-to-perform-this-operation-using-this/73390351#73390351) previously.

Comment: You were very enlightening. Thank you for sharing this answer. It's even better for me to study the subject :)