# Getting "Incorrect padding" error when trying to retrieve the list of blob names

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

- **azure-storage-blob**:
- **Version 12.19.1**:
- **Windows 10**:
- **Python 3.10.6**:
- **Over 10k files**:

**Describe the bug**
When attempting to retrieve the list of blob names from the Azure Blob Storage container, an "Incorrect padding" error is encountered. This issue seems to be causing a hindrance in fetching the blob names effectively, even though the blob upload and download operations have been successful.

**Code Snippet:**

```py
try:
    # Get the list of blobs in the container
    blob_list = self.container_client.list_blobs()

    print("List of blobs:")
    for blob in blob_list:
        print(blob.name)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred while retrieving the list of blobs: {str(e)}")
```

**Error Message:**
`Incorrect padding`

**Additional Successful Operations:**

- Blob Upload

```
def upload(self, blob_data, blob_name):
        try:
            # Upload a blob to the container
            self.container_client.upload_blob(name=blob_name, data=blob_data)
            print(f"Blob '{blob_name}' uploaded successfully.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while uploading blob '{blob_name}': {str(e)}")
```

- Blob Download

```
def download(self, blob_name):
        try:
            # Get the BlobClient for the blob
            blob_client = self.container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)

            # Download the blob to a local file
            with open(blob_name, "wb") as blob:
                download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
                blob.write(download_stream.readall())
            print(f"Blob '{blob_name}' downloaded successfully.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while downloading blob '{blob_name}': {str(e)}")
```

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have successfully connected to Azure Blob Storage and uploaded and downloaded certain data. Is this not relevant?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I updated, please review again. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that the issue is in the code, I think it must be configuration related.

Comment: Is there a status code returned in the exception?

Comment: @GauravMantri No status code received. It returned only the string value "Incorrect padding".

Comment: @GauravMantri I have over 10k files, could this be the reason?

Comment: @GauravMantri When I connected to Azure Blob Storage using an API key and tried to get a list of blobs, I received an "Incorrect padding" error message. However, after updating the Azure Blob Storage connection code with a SAS token, I encountered the following ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this. I hope this link will be helpful to your project config setting.

[Status 403: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73388655/status-403-this-request-is-not-authorized-to-perform-this-operation-using-this)

Comment: While the information in your link may solve the OP's question, link-only answers are discouraged for [these reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/236527). And given this links to an SO question, the correct response is to flag this question as a potential duplicate.

Comment: @LTyrone Oh, I see! So originally, there was a different issue, but as the progress continued, it evolved into an AuthorizationPermissionMismatch error. I recommend checking out the above comment. I upvote Ted's answer.